# Laravel 4 Paypal IPN Not Working TokenMismatchException

Tags: php, laravel, paypal-ipn, laravel-routing

I am simply adding a paypal IPN (using the https://github.com/mike182uk/paypal-ipn-listener)  to add credits to a users profile and add the order into the database. I actually had this working, but for some reason a day later, I noticed nothing being inserted into the DB and the users credits are not given. All I get in the laravel.log is this huge error log which seems to be all TokenMismatchException.

*FYI: I am using the paypal sandbox to do this right now, so not sure if that matters or not, but it's quite slow in responding.*

**Full error log for that specific call:**

```
    [2015-01-12 00:21:15] production.ERROR: exception 'Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException' in /home/username/webapps/site_name/app/filters.php:88
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: {closure}(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#1 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php(199): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#2 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php(154): Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher->fire('router.filter: ...', Array, true)
#3 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(1468): Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher->until('router.filter: ...', Array)
#4 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(240): Illuminate\Routing\Router->callRouteFilter('csrf', Array, Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#5 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(114): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->callFilter(Array, Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#6 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(55): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->before(Object(AuthController), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 'postLogin')
#7 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(962): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 'AuthController', 'postLogin')
#8 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}()
#9 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(109): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#10 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(1028): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#11 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(996): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#12 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(775): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#13 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(745): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#14 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware.php(72): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#15 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Queue.php(47): Illuminate\Session\Middleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#16 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Guard.php(51): Illuminate\Cookie\Queue->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#17 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/stack/builder/src/Stack/StackedHttpKernel.php(23): Illuminate\Cookie\Guard->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#18 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(641): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#19 /home/username/webapps/site_name/public/index.php(49): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run()
#20 {main} [] []
[2015-01-12 00:21:26] production.ERROR: exception 'Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException' in /home/username/webapps/site_name/app/filters.php:88
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: {closure}(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#1 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php(199): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#2 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php(154): Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher->fire('router.filter: ...', Array, true)
#3 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(1468): Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher->until('router.filter: ...', Array)
#4 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(240): Illuminate\Routing\Router->callRouteFilter('csrf', Array, Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#5 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(114): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->callFilter(Array, Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#6 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(55): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->before(Object(AuthController), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 'postLogin')
#7 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(962): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 'AuthController', 'postLogin')
#8 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}()
#9 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(109): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#10 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(1028): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#11 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(996): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#12 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(775): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#13 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(745): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#14 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware.php(72): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#15 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Queue.php(47): Illuminate\Session\Middleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#16 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Guard.php(51): Illuminate\Cookie\Queue->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#17 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/stack/builder/src/Stack/StackedHttpKernel.php(23): Illuminate\Cookie\Guard->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#18 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(641): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#19 /home/username/webapps/site_name/public/index.php(49): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run()
#20 {main} [] []
[2015-01-12 00:21:46] production.ERROR: exception 'Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException' in /home/username/webapps/site_name/app/filters.php:88
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: {closure}(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#1 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php(199): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#2 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php(154): Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher->fire('router.filter: ...', Array, true)
#3 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(1468): Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher->until('router.filter: ...', Array)
#4 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(240): Illuminate\Routing\Router->callRouteFilter('csrf', Array, Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#5 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(114): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->callFilter(Array, Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#6 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(55): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->before(Object(AuthController), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 'postLogin')
#7 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(962): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 'AuthController', 'postLogin')
#8 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}()
#9 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(109): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#10 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(1028): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#11 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(996): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#12 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(775): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#13 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(745): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#14 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware.php(72): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#15 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Queue.php(47): Illuminate\Session\Middleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#16 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Guard.php(51): Illuminate\Cookie\Queue->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#17 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/stack/builder/src/Stack/StackedHttpKernel.php(23): Illuminate\Cookie\Guard->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#18 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(641): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#19 /home/username/webapps/site_name/public/index.php(49): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run()
#20 {main} [] []
[2015-01-12 00:22:10] production.ERROR: exception 'Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException' in /home/username/webapps/site_name/app/filters.php:88
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: {closure}(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#1 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php(199): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#2 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php(154): Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher->fire('router.filter: ...', Array, true)
#3 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(1468): Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher->until('router.filter: ...', Array)
#4 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(240): Illuminate\Routing\Router->callRouteFilter('csrf', Array, Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#5 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(114): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->callFilter(Array, Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#6 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(55): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->before(Object(AuthController), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 'postLogin')
#7 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(962): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 'AuthController', 'postLogin')
#8 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}()
#9 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(109): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#10 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(1028): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#11 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(996): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#12 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(775): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#13 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(745): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#14 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware.php(72): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#15 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Queue.php(47): Illuminate\Session\Middleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#16 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Guard.php(51): Illuminate\Cookie\Queue->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#17 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/stack/builder/src/Stack/StackedHttpKernel.php(23): Illuminate\Cookie\Guard->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#18 /home/username/webapps/site_name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(641): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#19 /home/username/webapps/site_name/public/index.php(49): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run()
#20 {main} [] []
```

Not even sure what TokenMismatchException has to do with the Paypal IPN since I don't have csrf enabled on the routes for it. Peep the Controller/routes below:

**IpnController**

```
use PayPal\Ipn\Listener;
use PayPal\Ipn\Message;
use PayPal\Ipn\Verifier\CurlVerifier;

class IpnController extends BaseController {

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store()
    {
        $listener = new Listener;
        $verifier = new CurlVerifier;
        $ipnMessage = Message::createFromGlobals(); // uses php://input

        $verifier->setIpnMessage($ipnMessage);
        if ( Config::get( 'app.debug' ) ) {
            $verifier->setEnvironment('sandbox'); // Use sandbox if debug is true
        } else {
            $verifier->setEnvironment('production');
        }

        $listener->setVerifier($verifier);

        $listener->listen( function() use ( $listener )
        {
            // on verified IPN (everything is good!)
            $resp = $listener->getVerifier()->getVerificationResponse();
            $data = Input::all();

            $order = new CreditOrder;
            $order->txn_id = $data['txn_id'];
            $order->payer_email = $data['payer_email'];
            $order->user_id = $data['custom'];
            $order->product_id = $data['item_number'];
            $order->mc_gross = $data['mc_gross'];
            $order->save();

            $product = Product::find( $data['item_number'] );
            $user = User::find( $data['custom'] );
            $user->increment( 'credits', $product->credit_amount );

            Mail::send( 'emails.credits.thankyou', [ 'username' => $user->username, 'package' => $product->product, 'credits' => $product->credit_amount, 'price' => $product->price ], function( $message ) {
                $message->to( 'email@gmail.com', 'Name' )->subject( 'Name - Credits Added!' );
            });
        },
        function() use ( $listener )
        {
            // on invalid IPN (somethings not right!)
            $report = $listener->getReport();
            $resp = $listener->getVerifier()->getVerificationResponse();
            Log::error('invalid IPN');
            Mail::send( 'emails.plain', [ 'content' => $report ], function( $message ) {
                $message->to( 'email@gmail.com', 'Name' )->subject( 'Name Invalid IPN' );
            });
        });
    }

    public function cancel()
    {
        return Redirect::route( 'credits.packages' )->with( 'error', 'Your payment was canceled.' );
    }

    public function success()
    {
        return View::make( 'credits.success' );
        // return Redirect::home()->with( 'success', '<strong>Thank you, '. Auth::user()->username .'!</strong> Your payment was successful and your account has been credited.' );
    }
}
```

**IPN Routes**

```
Route::group( [ 'before' => 'auth' ], function()
{
    // IPN
    Route::post('/credits/ipn', [ 'uses' => 'IpnController@store', 'as' => 'credits.ipn' ] );
    Route::get('/credits/cancel', [ 'uses' => 'IpnController@cancel', 'as' => 'credits.cancel' ] );
    Route::post('/credits/success', [ 'uses' => 'IpnController@success', 'as' => 'credits.success' ] );
});
```

If you need me to add any additional info, please let me know. I've been struggling with this for a few days now and really need to get this figured out this week! Appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just by taking my IPN routes out of the "before auth" group, it seems to be working fine now?

Someone did mention something about the csrf being enabled by default on post routes. So that could have something to do with it as well. Just in case, I used their suggestion here:
http://laravel.io/forum/01-12-2015-laravel-4-paypal-ipn-not-working-tokenmismatchexception?page=1#reply-19578

All seems to be working now though.
Cheers!